# How do I install XCache in WAMP in windows?

Tags: php, xcache

How to Install XCache in WAMP server [XCache](https://xcache.lighttpd.net/)

I got XCache is not loaded

[image]

Comment: May I know why its downgraded?

Comment: I'd recommend to have a read of the best practice when asking a question mentioned here > http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Try to be more specific, what have you tried? what issues are you facing? etc

Comment: My question is Straight forward, How can I Install XCache in WAMP Server, I followed steps provided in XCache site, but its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download xcache curesponding to your PHP version from [here](https://xcache.lighttpd.net/pub/Releases/2.0.1-rc1/)
2. Open php.ini and comment APC, memcache, disable memcache service.
3. Add the `extension = php_xcache.dll` to php.ini
4. Copy php_xcache.dll to the php ext dirctory.
5. Open xcache.ini, copy & paste all to the end of php.ini (right before ; End:)
6. Edit the path to php_xcache.dll, example: `zend_extension_ts = C:/xampp/php/ext/php_xcache.dll`
7. Set the xcache admin username and password. Use any username. Generate a 32 digit md5 password.
8. Restart apache and check phpinfo.

php.ini section will look like

`[xcache-common]
zend_extension_ts = C:/xampp/php/ext/php_xcache.dll`

`[xcache.admin]
xcache.admin.enable_auth = On
xcache.admin.user = "anyusername"
xcache.admin.pass = "32-digit-number"`

Comment: I followed your steps, but I can not find **php_xcache**

Comment: Please check my edit

Comment: Still its saying

XCache is not loaded

Please check D:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini

Comment: thanks @Harikrishnan.